# Filling NaN rows in big pandas datetime indexed dataframe using other not NaN rows values

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, nan, fillna

I have a big weather csv dataframe containing several hundred thousand of rows as well many columns. The rows are time-series sampled every 10 minutes over many years. The index data column that represents datetime consists of year, month, day, hour, minute and second. Unfortunately, there were several thousand missing rows containing only NaNs. The goal is to fill these ones using the values of other rows collected at the same time but of other years if they are not NaNs.

I wrote a python for loop code but it seems like a very time consuming solution. I need your help for a more efficient and faster solution.

The raw dataframe is as follows:

```
print(df)
```

```
                    p (mbar)  T (degC)  Tpot (K)  Tdew (degC)  rh (%)
datetime                                                              
2004-01-01 00:10:00    996.52     -8.02    265.40        -8.90   93.30
2004-01-01 00:20:00    996.57     -8.41    265.01        -9.28   93.40
2004-01-01 00:40:00    996.51     -8.31    265.12        -9.07   94.20
2004-01-01 00:50:00    996.51     -8.27    265.15        -9.04   94.10
2004-01-01 01:00:00    996.53     -8.51    264.91        -9.31   93.90
...                       ...       ...       ...          ...     ...
2020-12-31 23:20:00   1000.07     -4.05    269.10        -8.13   73.10
2020-12-31 23:30:00    999.93     -3.35    269.81        -8.06   69.71
2020-12-31 23:40:00    999.82     -3.16    270.01        -8.21   67.91
2020-12-31 23:50:00    999.81     -4.23    268.94        -8.53   71.80
2021-01-01 00:00:00    999.82     -4.82    268.36        -8.42   75.70

[820551 rows x 5 columns]
```

For any reason, there were missing rows in the df dataframe. To identify them, it is possible to apply the below function:

```
findnanrows(df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='10T')).mean())
```

```
                     p (mbar)  T (degC)  Tpot (K)  Tdew (degC)  rh (%)
datetime 
2004-01-01 00:30:00       NaN       NaN       NaN          NaN     NaN                                                             
2009-10-08 09:50:00       NaN       NaN       NaN          NaN     NaN
2009-10-08 10:00:00       NaN       NaN       NaN          NaN     NaN
2013-05-16 09:00:00       NaN       NaN       NaN          NaN     NaN
2014-07-30 08:10:00       NaN       NaN       NaN          NaN     NaN
...                       ...       ...       ...          ...     ...
2016-10-28 12:00:00       NaN       NaN       NaN          NaN     NaN
2016-10-28 12:10:00       NaN       NaN       NaN          NaN     NaN
2016-10-28 12:20:00       NaN       NaN       NaN          NaN     NaN
2016-10-28 12:30:00       NaN       NaN       NaN          NaN     NaN
2016-10-28 12:40:00       NaN       NaN       NaN          NaN     NaN

[5440 rows x 5 columns]
```

The aim is to fill all these NaN rows. As an example, the first NaN row which corresponds to the datetime `2004-01-01 00:30:00` should be filled with the not NaN values of another row collected on the same datetime `xxxx-01-01 00:30:00` of another year like `2005-01-01 00:30:00` or `2006-01-01 00:30:00` and so on, even `2003-01-01 00:30:00` or `2002-01-01 00:30:00` if they existing. It is possible to apply an average over all these other years.

Seeing the values of the row with the datetime index `2005-01-01 00:30:00`:

```
print(df.loc["2005-01-01 00:30:00", :])
```

```
                     p (mbar)  T (degC)  Tpot (K)  Tdew (degC)  rh (%)
datetime                                                              
2005-01-01 00:30:00    996.36     12.67    286.13         7.11   68.82
```

After filling the row corresponding to the index datetime `2004-01-01 00:30:00` using the values of the row having the index datetime `2005-01-01 00:30:00`, the df dataframe will have the following row:

```
print(df.loc["2004-01-01 00:30:00", :])
```

```
                     p (mbar)  T (degC)  Tpot (K)  Tdew (degC)  rh (%)
datetime                                                              
2004-01-01 00:30:00    996.36     12.67    286.13         7.11   68.82
```

The two functions that I created are the following. The first is to identify the NaN rows. The second is to fill them.

```
def findnanrows(df):
    is_NaN = df.isnull() 
    row_has_NaN = is_NaN.any(axis=1) 
    rows_with_NaN = df[row_has_NaN] 
    return rows_with_NaN

def filldata(weatherdata):
    fillweatherdata = weatherdata.copy()
    allyears = fillweatherdata.index.year.unique().tolist()
    dfnan = findnanrows(fillweatherdata.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='10T')).mean())
    for i in range(dfnan.shape[0]):
        dnan = dfnan.index[i]
        if dnan.year == min(allyears):
            y = 0
            dnew = dnan.replace(year=dnan.year+y)
            while dnew in dfnan.index:
                dnew = dnew.replace(year=dnew.year+y)
                y += 1   
        else:
            y = 0
            dnew = dnan.replace(year=dnan.year-y)
            while dnew in dfnan.index:
                dnew = dnew.replace(year=dnew.year-y)
                y += 1
        new_row = pd.DataFrame(np.array([fillweatherdata.loc[dnew, :]]).tolist(), columns=fillweatherdata.columns.tolist(), index=[dnan])
        fillweatherdata = pd.concat([fillweatherdata, pd.DataFrame(new_row)], ignore_index=False)
    #fillweatherdata = fillweatherdata.drop_duplicates()
    fillweatherdata = fillweatherdata.sort_index()
    return fillweatherdata
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you give a part of the input data as an example, e.g. 10 lines with at least one line with the nan's

Comment: What is you actual question?

Comment: I reformulated my question with an input data as example.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more appropriate to interpolate values from data immediately before and after the missing data if available?  The weather from ten minutes ago seems like it would be a much better predictor of the current weather than the weather at exactly this minute last year.

Comment: If you decide interpolation is a good approach, I would simply use `df.interpolate()`.